# What's the correct way for using the same onclick listener for more views in android?

Tags: android, view, onclick, listener, onclicklistener

I'm trying to port my Windows Phone application to Android and i'm having some problems in associating the same onclicklistener to more views.
My custom view code is:

```
public class Cerchio extends View{

    private float x;
    private float y;
    private Paint paint;

    public Cerchio(Context c, float x, float y, Paint paint) {
        super(c);
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.paint = paint;

    }

    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawCircle(x, y, 30, this.paint);
    }
}
```

And here i create views with listeners:

```
RelativeLayout gridLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.grid_layout);
        for (Punto p : gr.getPunti()){ //creating visible grid
            float x = (dpToPx(300) / (gr.getX()-1) * (p.getX()-1)) + dpToPx(15);
            float y = (dpToPx(300) / (gr.getY()-1) * (p.getY()-1)) + dpToPx(15);
            Cerchio cerchio = new Cerchio(this, x, y, paintbianca);
            cerchio.setTag(p);
            cerchio.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    move(v);
                }
            });
            gridLayout.addView(cerchio);
        }
```

Finally, the beginning of my move function:

```
public void move(View v) {
        Cerchio cerchio = (Cerchio) v;
        Punto p = (Punto) v.getTag();
        RelativeLayout gridLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.grid_layout);
```

What happens is that, no matter which view i'm clicking, Android keeps thinking that i'm clicking always the same view (the last one added in the for statement).
So, basically, what i need is to understand the correct way for catching the clicked view.

Thanks in advance to everyone who will help me :)

Edit: Here is the full code of move method:

```
public void move(View v) {
        Cerchio cerchio = (Cerchio) v;
        Punto p = (Punto) v.getTag();
        RelativeLayout gridLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.grid_layout);

        if (p.Equals(selezionato)) //sto ricliccando il punto
        {
            selezionato = null;
            cerchio.setLayerPaint(paintbianca);//deseleziono l'ellisse visivamente
            for(Linea l : linee){ //rimuovo le linee
                gridLayout.removeView(l);
        }
            linee.clear();
        }
        else if (selezionato != null) //sto collegando 2 punti
        {
            if (gr.ControllaMossa(p, selezionato)) //se la mossa è consentita collego i 2 punti e continuo
            {
                for (Linea l : linee) //rimuovo le linee
                {
                    gridLayout.removeView(l);
                }
                cerchiosel.setLayerPaint(paintbianca); //deseleziono l'ellisse visivamente
                linee.clear();

                int x1 = dpToPx((int) (cerchio.getX() + 15));
                int y1 = dpToPx((int) (cerchio.getY() + 15));
                int x2 = dpToPx((0 + (300 / (gr.getX() - 1) * (selezionato.getX() - 1))) + 15);
                int y2 = dpToPx((int)((300 - (310.0 / (gr.getY() - 1) * (selezionato.getY() - 1))) + 15));
                Linea linea = new Linea(this,x1,y1,x2,y2,paintbianca); //disegno la linea che collega i 2 punti
                gridLayout.addView(linea);

                ArrayList<Punto> ls = gr.TrovaTriangolo(p,selezionato);
                for (Punto q : ls)
                {
                    float X1 = dpToPx((int)cerchio.getX());
                    float Y1 = dpToPx((int)cerchio.getY());
                    float X2 = dpToPx(0 + (300 / (gr.getX() - 1) * (selezionato.getX() - 1)) + 15);
                    float Y2 = dpToPx(310 - (300 / (gr.getY() - 1) * (selezionato.getY() - 1)) + 15);
                    float X3 = dpToPx(0 + (300 / (gr.getX() - 1) * (q.getX() - 1)) + 15);
                    float Y3 = dpToPx(310 - (300 / (gr.getY() - 1) * (q.getY() - 1)) + 15);
                    if (turno == 0) //coloro il triangolo a seconda del giocatore e assegno l'area
                    {
                        Triangolo triangolo = new Triangolo(this,X1,Y1,X2,Y2,X3,Y3,paintazzurra); //creo il triangolo
                        g1.AumentaArea(gr.AreaTriangolo(p,selezionato,q));
                        triangolig1++;
                        TextView textg1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textG1);
                        textg1.setText(g1.getNome() + "\n Score: " + triangolig1);
                        gridLayout.addView(triangolo);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Triangolo triangolo = new Triangolo(this,X1,Y1,X2,Y2,X3,Y3,paintviola); //creo il triangolo
                        g2.AumentaArea(gr.AreaTriangolo(p, selezionato, q));
                        triangolig2++;
                        TextView textg2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textG2);
                        textg2.setText(g2.getNome() + "\n Score: " + triangolig2);
                        gridLayout.addView(triangolo);
                    }
                }
                if (ls.size() == 0) //cambio di turno
                {
                    turno = (turno + 1) % 2;
                }

                /*if (turno == 0) //gestisco il turno visivamente
                {
                    EP1.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
                    EP2.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
                }
                else
                {
                    EP1.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
                    EP2.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
                }*/

                gr.Linka(selezionato, p);
                gr.AggiornaADJ(selezionato, p);
                selezionato = null;

                //gestisco la fine della partita
                double area = (gr.getX()-1) * (gr.getY()-1);
                double a = g1.getArea() + g2.getArea();
                double range =Math.abs(a - area);

                if (range>=0 && range<=0.1)
                {
                    int vincitore = CalcolaVincitore();
                    AlertDialog.Builder dlgAlert  = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                    dlgAlert.setTitle("Finish");
                    dlgAlert.setPositiveButton("OK",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                            finish();
                        }
                    });
                    dlgAlert.setCancelable(true);
                    switch (vincitore)
                    {
                        case 0:

                            dlgAlert.setMessage("Draw");
                            dlgAlert.create().show();
                            break;
                        case 1:

                            dlgAlert.setMessage(g1.getNome() + " won");
                            dlgAlert.create().show();
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            dlgAlert.setMessage(g2.getNome() + " won");
                            dlgAlert.create().show();
                            break;
                    }

                }

            }
            else //se la mossa non è consentita tocca ancora a quel giocatore
            {
                AlertDialog.Builder dlgAlert  = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                dlgAlert.setTitle("Attention");
                dlgAlert.setMessage("Move not allowed");
                dlgAlert.setPositiveButton("OK",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        finish();
                    }
                });
                dlgAlert.setCancelable(true);
                dlgAlert.create().show();
            }
        }
        else //sto selezionando il primo punto
        {
            selezionato = p;
            cerchiosel = cerchio;
            cerchiosel.setLayerPaint(paintgialla); //deseleziono l'ellisse visivamente
            for (Tupla t : gr.getLista()) //illumino i possibili collegamenti
            {
                if (p.Equals(t.getPuntoA()) && t.getLinked() == false)
                {
                    int x1 = dpToPx((int) (cerchio.getX() + 15));
                    int y1 = dpToPx((int) (cerchio.getY() + 15));
                    int x2 = dpToPx(((0 + (300 / (gr.getX() - 1) * (t.getPuntoB().getX() - 1))) + 15));
                    int y2 = dpToPx((310 - (300 / (gr.getY() - 1) * (t.getPuntoB().getY() - 1))) + 15);
                    Linea linea = new Linea(this,x1,y1,x2,y2,painttratteggiata);
                    gridLayout.addView(linea);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

EDIT 2: I solved my problem by replacing my custom views (Cerchio) with buttons. Thanks again to everyone who tried to help me!

Comment: Is it possible that all your views are occupying the same space? (you can check this using View Hierarchy)

Comment: The problem is likely in the `move` method, please post the remaining code.

Comment: Unless njzk2 is correct I would suggest Mister Smith has it right. The code you've shown us looks like it should work. It looks like we're missing something.

Comment: I just posted the full code above :)
And no, views are not occupying the same space (at least i see them in their right position)

Comment: I posted only those lines because the problem is that using the debugger i see that the called view (in Cerchio cerchio = (Cerchio) v) is always the same.

Comment: So you did see multiple Cerchio on the screen? The line ``gridLayout.removeView(l);`` is a bit worrying - you are handling events for one view in ``gridLayout`` while you are removing some others.

Comment: That's right: I see all the circles I wanted to see. Inside move I'm removing other views because that's what my game has to do: show lines and remove them when needed :)

Comment: I tried using hierarchyviewer as suggested by @njzk2 and everything is exactly where i supposed to be.